# PHP readfile() not forcing download

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-io, download

When I run the function below it locates and reads the file, displaying the results in the my Chrome Dev Tools preview tab correctly in the csv format. But it's not downloading it. If I link directly to the file in my browser it downloads it, so it doesn't appear to be an .htaccess issue. I've used the example in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) and many variations of it found here on Stack Overflow but the results are the same: the file displays in my preview tab in dev tools (and the same goes with Firefox as well) but no download. My code:

```
public function download()
{
    $file = $this->dir;

    if (file_exists($file)) {

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. $file);
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }       
}
```

I'm developing locally with latest Wamp server. When I push/pull to my remote, the result is the same.

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think your headers are getting removed when you call ob_clean.  I would try putting ob_clean and flush before the headers.

Comment: Tried using the sample code from php.net and it works. Seems like you're running into AJAX-problems, see @MajorCaiger's answer, as the beat me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, it sounds like you might be trying to download your file via an AJAX request.

If so, I don't believe you can do this. Instead you could open the link to the file in a new window, which will successfully download the file.

Comment: Absolutely correct. You can't initiate a download via AJAX (for security reasons)

Comment: That's what it was. I knew you couldn't directly download with ajax but I did not know that if I passsed the params to a php function it would not download. I guess the assumption was that the PHP wouldn't 'know' I was using js. But the browser does... Much thanks!